Serenity BDD - Empty reports when large test scenarios executed
Some of the test scenarios were not captured in the serenity-bdd reporter.
If i run them independent, the report is empty - 0 Tests. However, log shows the test was run and passed.
I'm using serenity-bdd to generate reports.
Does anyone have any solution that they came across?
My config:
Serenity-js v3.23.2, serenity-js/serenity-bdd v3.23.2 (using 4.1.6.jar), cucumber v10.7.0, wdio v8.38.0.
Would be much appreciated if anyone came across this issue with my kind off setup.
I tried with serenity with v3.12.0 and bdd 3.1.1, cucumber v9.6.0 and wdio 8.26.0.
